# What is a free kill in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

I often read or hear that term even if they're referring to some full hp target.

I could think that as a kill that has no damage risk at all, but I'm not feeling sure about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Free kill' is a term that is used to refer to *any* objective that can be taken by a team (or player) where there is **little to no risk** to the team (or player) to take it.

This includes champions, turrets and objectives.

For instance, if a team won an early teamfight at bottom 4 kills to 1, and their health and damage are still good, then Dragon might be considered a 'free kill'. The same situation can happen with Baron.

In other cases, a team may push down to 1 or 2 inhibitors and choose to return to base. On their way back out - due to the pressure provided by the super minions - they may choose to push the remaining lane - which could guarded by an outer turret. Because of that team's map control and pressure in other lanes, this outer turret is likely a 'free kill' (regardless of health) as it would be too risky for the other team to defend it.

Similarly, if a champion is overextended, underleveled, unskilled or alone, the champion may be considered a 'free kill'. ([See Justschge's answer)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174227/what-is-a-free-kill-in-lol/174228#174228)

Answer (score 3):

A free kill is basically just a Champion that is easy to kill. Players use this phrase if it is almost impossible to lose a Duel or Fight (or a kill) against a certain champion.

Most of the time "Freekills" are overextended in lanes, far behind/underleveled or extremely unskilled. Sometimes people also say "Oh this is a free kill" to champions they counter hard with their current champion.